Is it correct to write "cars' condition" in the meaning "condition of cars"
I want to write as concisely as possible the phrase "Drivers complained about the condition of their cars", can I shorten it like this "Drivers complained about cars' condition"? Is it valid to use a possessive noun in this case?

What problem are you thinking this might have?

Grammarly often removes possessives for plural nouns in cases like this one above, so I'm trying to determine if there is a mistake and why.

Well yes, that would be a bug in the software.

I might prefer "Drivers complained about their cars' conditions".

"Drivers complained about cars' condition" isn't really grammatical; it's in a shortened note form (omitting articles/determiners) which is fine for notes. But you could shorten it further to "car condition", or maybe omit "car(s')" entirely.

@StuartF Thank you for your comment. Did I understand correctly that the full form can be "Drivers complained about the cars' condition" and the shortened note is "Drivers complained about car condition"?

@Henry thank you for your comment!

I think the possible issue is that cars' refers to many cars but "condition" means they all share one condition. Because each car is presumably its own unique mess, I think "cars' conditions" would be better.
